# How to set up displacement maps when using UDIM textures?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I recently started using UDIMs so there might be something really obvious that I don't get.

I sculpted model in Zbrush. I exported displacement maps from Zbrush and everything works ok with UDIMs so far. But how do I use them in Blender?

I usually add modifiers; multires + displacement. But as I now have UDIMs I can't get it to work. I realized that I can switch in texture tab the source being UDIM tile(so I might be getting somewhere?) but can't figure how to import all those maps. I also tried adding displacement straight in shader editor, but couldn't get that to work either.

Trying to find something about this online is really hard, so little info about this. So what is the right workflow? Hopefully there is someone who has experience on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Blender (version 2.93.5) requires UDIM file set to have suffix `_1001`, `_1002` etc, with no numbering gaps. Make it so by going to ZBrush Multi Map Exporter, click "File names", and choose `<UDIM>` in "UV tile ID format". In the same dialog also change "Map type suffix" from `-DM` to `-DM_`. Now when you export a displacement map, you should get appropriately named files.

[image: ZBrush Multi Map Exporter]
[image: ZBrush File Names dialog]

In Blender Image editor's Image tab, make sure "Source" is "UDIM Tiles". If there is only one entry in the "UDIM Tiles" list, add more by clicking the plus icon. Now reload the image, and you should see additional UDIM tiles appear next to the original one in the image editor.

[image: Blender Image dialog]

Blender bug tracker entry https://developer.blender.org/T77989 is about these issues.